# Pandas - append DataFrame with varying columns in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have been struggling with appending multiple `DataFrames` with varying `columns` and, would really appreciate your help with this problem!

My original data set looks like below

```
 df1 = height 10
       color  25
       weight 3
       speed  33

 df2 = height 51
       color  25
       weight 30
       speed  33

 df3 = height 51
       color  25
       speed 30
```

I call `transform_csv_data(csv_data, row)` function to first add `name` on the last row. Then I `transpose` and move the  `name` which becomes the last column to the first column for every `DataFrame` so each `DataFrame` looks like below before appending (but before moving the last column to front)

```
df1 = 
   0        1       2       3       4
0  height   color   weight  speed   name
1  10       25      3       33      Joe

df2 =
   0        1       2       3       4
0  height   color   weight  speed   name
1  51       25      30      33      Bob

df3 = 
   0        1       2       3        
0  height   color   speed   name    
1  51       25      30      Chris
```

The problem is appending `DataFrames` with different number of `columns` and each `DataFrame` contains two rows including `header` and `Data` as above.

The code for `transform_csv_data` helper function is shown below

```
def transform_csv_data(self, csv_data, row):
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(csv_data))

    df = df.iloc[:, [0, -2]]  # all rows with first and second last column
    df.loc[len(df)] = ['name', row]

    df = df.transpose()

    cols = df.columns.values.tolist() # this returns index of each column
    cols.insert(0, cols.pop(-1))  # move last column to front
    df = df.reindex(columns=cols)

    return df
```

My main function for appending `DataFrame` is shown below

```
def aggregate_data(self, output_data_file_path):
    df_output = pd.DataFrame()
    rows = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Chris']

    for index, row in enumerate(rows):

        csv_data = self.read_csv_url(row)
        df = self.transform_csv_data(csv_data, row)

        # ignore header unless first set of data is being processed
        if index != 0 or append:
            df = df[1:]

        df_output = df_output.append(df)
        df_output.to_csv(output_data_file_path, index=False, header=False, mode='a+')
```

I want my final appended `DatFrame` to become as below but format becomes weird as the `name` column goes back to the end of the `column`

```
final = 
 name     height    color   weight  speed
 Joe      10        25      3       33         
 Bob      51        25      30      33      
 Chris    51        25      nan     30
```

How can I append all the `DataFrame` properly so `data` is appended to its corresponding `column`?

I have tried adding `concat`, `merge`, `df_output = df_output.append(df_row)[df_output.columns.tolist()]` but no luck so far

There are also duplicate columns which I would like to keep.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: `df1=pd.read_csv('x',index_col=[0],header=[0,1])..;pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)`